# Group dataframe by columns containing specific value R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
Type    June 23   June 24   July 23    July 24    August 23    August 24
 A         8        2          20         20           30         25
 B         8        2          20         20           30         25
```

Now I want to have the sum over the columns per month (so disregarding the week number). So, the result should look like this

```
Type    June   July   August
 A       10     40      55        
 B       10     40      55
```

I try do this this using dplyr, but I do not know how to match only the first part of the column names. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, you can use `split.default` to split data based on similar part of column names.

In your example, if we remove numbers from column names we get the month name, pass it to `split.default` and sum each part using `rowSums`.

```
cbind(df[1],sapply(split.default(df[-1], sub('\\d+', '',names(df[-1]))), rowSums))

#  Type August July June
#1    A     55   40   10
#2    B     55   40   10
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Type = c("A", "B"), June23 = c(8L, 8L), June24 = c(2L, 
2L), July23 = c(20L, 20L), July24 = c(20L, 20L), August23 = c(30L, 
30L), August24 = c(25L, 25L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution implying the `tidyverse` universe could be

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Type) %>% 
  mutate(Month = str_extract(name, "\\D+")) %>% 
  group_by(Type, Month) %>% 
  summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols = Type, names_from = Month, values_from = Sum)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   Type [2]
#   Type  August  July  June
#   <chr>  <int> <int> <int>
# 1 A         55    40    10
# 2 B         55    40    10
```